# Execution plan, SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a question about execution plan:

I wrote a query before I approve it execution plan use clustered index scan with 2 row on reads:

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 17
Table 'a21'. Scan count 3, logical reads 6
```

after I create index seek execution plain use index seek

```
Scan count 43, logical reads 86.
```

What's better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tell from the numbers because it does not show you which reads were physical, which were logical and how costly each read was. The read/write numbers are almost worthless.

Instead, measure CPU time used. For your workload it is extremely likely that there is no physical IO because the tables are so small. So don't measure IO.

Also, compare the execution plans.

Comment: @SurajSingh do you think a query with 1000 reads is 10 times slower than a query with 100 reads? No. You can't even tell that it is faster at all. The query with 100 reads might burn 10s of CPU while the other might use almost no CPU. Or the 100 reads might be physical while the 1000 might be cached (which means they are almost free). The IO numbers tell you very little about performance.

Comment: No i really do not go with the numbers 10 times slower etc., So read/write do not affect CPU time or performance in any way?

Comment: If you want to know CPU time, look at the CPU time value. Or at the elapsed wall clock time. `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` gives you information like `CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 106 ms.`. I usually turn on client statistics in SSMS and look at the wall clock time.